# When a multi-parameter estimation problem can be considered as a single-parameter estimation problem?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation, fisher-information

Suppose we have a simple neural network described by a [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron). The figure below can be seen as a schematic representation of this model.

[image: Perceptron]

Basically, each input $x_i$ gets multiplied by a weight factor $w_i$ and the weighted sum of the inputs is sent to the activation function $f(x)$ which produces the output $y$. I want to determine the estimation errors of the weights of the neural network using the probability distribution of the output of the activation function. Naturally, I have to use multivariate parameter estimation paradigm and [Fisher information matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Matrix_form) to find the bounds on the errors of the estimators using [Cramér–Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound).

The first question is, if we assume that all the weights ($w_i$) are equal, is it justified to use single-parameter estimation estimation theory and say that the bound is given by the reciprocal of the Fisher information for that single parameter? Basically, if the $w_i$ are identical at all times, does it mean that they are the same random variable even if they correspond to different nodes of the network with different inputs?

The second question is, is there a condition at all that if it is satisfied we are allowed to reduce the multi-parameter estimation problem to a single-parameter one in general (not only for this problem)?

I must add that the off-diagonal entries of the Fisher information matrix (FIM) that I have calculated when treating each $w_i$ as a distinct random variable are non-zero. Having non-zero off-diagonals in the FIM in general affects the error bounds in multivariable parameter estimation. Is this calculation justified or should I stick with the single parameter Fisher information because I actually have only one random variable?

Comment: I think it depends on whether you can update the weights independently. If your model requires all the weights to remain equal, then it's really just a single-parameter model, but if the weights are independent parameters that just happen to have equal values at a given stage of training, then you should treat them as separate. If the whole network is in a symmetric state so that the output gradient is the same with respect to each weight, then these situations are (sort of accidentally) equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, what you mean is that if the weights are equal at all times they are only 1 random variable and I shouldn't use Fisher information matrix, right?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how [estimation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory) is applied to the neural network - what are the "true" weights and what are the estimates? I was imagining you're trying to [backpropagate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) the output error to compute "errors" in the weights.